# gsub replacestring error with R under Windows

Tags: r, linux, windows, gsub

I develloped the following functional R script under Ubuntu

```
lbcordiprice2 <- gsub('\n', '', lbcordiprice1)
lbcordiprice3 <- gsub('\t', '', lbcordiprice2)
lbcordiprice4 <- gsub(' ', '', lbcordiprice3)
lbcordiprice5 <- gsub('€', '', lbcordiprice4)
lbcordiprice6 <- gsub(' ', '', lbcordiprice5)
lbcordiprice7 <- as.numeric(lbcordiprice6)
```

under Windows, it fails. Specifically,

```
lbcordiprice5 <- gsub('€', '', lbcordiprice4)
```

fails to transform the following vector

lbcordiprice4
 [1] "750 €"   "4900 €"  "9000 €"  "21900 €" "40 €"    "4390 €"  "100 €"   "1 €"     "30 €"    "23900 €" "210 €"
[12] "3200 €"  "22900 €" "25 €"    "30 €"    "30000 €" "400 €"   "20 €"    "16900 €" "15 €"    "20 €"    "180 €"

into

lbcordiprice5
 [1] "750 "   "4900 "  "9000 "  "21900 " "40 "    "4390 "  "100 "   "1 "     "30 "    "23900 " "210 "
[12] "3200 "  "22900 " "25 "    "30 "    "30000 " "400 "   "20 "    "16900 " "15 "    "20 "    "180 "

I have a sense that the problem is with the encoding, but I can't quite get it right.

Comment: You can do them all at once by using a character class for the pattern: `'[\\n\\t €]+'`. (Also, you need to double-escape.) `readr::parse_number` could probably do everything for you, anyway, though.

Comment: Works fine on my Windows machine

Comment: as opposed to stripping off the extra characters, just extract the number part: `library(stringr)`; `lbcordiprice5 <-str_extract(s, "\\d*")`

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for the responses, I'd upvote them but for their being in the comments.

Comment: I'm also a little curious generally as to why the euro symbol won't budge, but will do on G5W's machine.